# OSError: [WinError 10038] webserver

Tags: python, sockets, webserver

I have made a simple Python web server.
The server runs fine, connects to browser, and sends data.
When I have files included to to the HTML doc I'm sending (like `<img src="image_path"/>`)

It doesn't want to send the data, nor other ones included, like style sheets. I am using Chrome Web browser, and getting thoose headers:

```
GET /img.jpg HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
Chrome/24.0.1312.57 Safari/537.17
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost/
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: pl,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6,nb;q=0.4
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-2,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
```

And I get this error message:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function handler at 0x02C28150>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\CamIce\Desktop\PyServer v2\server.py", line 16, in handler
data = clientsock.recv(BUFSIZ)
OSError: [WinError 10038] Próbowano przeprowadzić próbę na obiekcie, który nie jest  
gniazdem
```

The code is too long for this message, so I had to post it on pastebin:
http://pastebin.com/n19J0y6A

Comment: In case anybody was wondering, as I was, the error translates: 
Socket operation on nonsocket.

    An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket. Either the socket handle parameter did not reference a valid socket, or for select, a member of an fd_set was not valid.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried binding your incoming socket to a different, non-privileged port instead of port 80 (say, something above 1024)?  This seems to me like the Windows firewall is interfering somehow, or possibly some other permission issue. It just seems odd to me that you didn't get an error before the recv() call, but I don't know WIndows too well.

I don't see anything immediately wrong with your code.

Comment: Although as an aside, you really should consider using `threading.Thread` instead of the lower-level `thread` library.  You don't need the `from _thread import *` at all.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've tried on many different ports, wit hthe same result. The server launches the index.html file, and is also sending the not found file, but if I try to get other files, like img.jpg, style.css or a txt file I placed in there, It's not working.

Comment: I'vefixed the problem with the server not sending data. I forgot to format the requested file, so it deleted the / from beginning (in http headers all requests start by /). But I am still getting the same error, which is quite annoying, and would probably show in the log file I am planning to add, which I don't want :(